# Accessing WCF service hosted on IIS7.5 from desktop application

Tags: c#, wcf, sql-server-2008, windows

I have created a WCF service application which is connected to SQL server 2008 .

I have successfully hosted the service application to my IIS 7.5

I now want to access this WCF service from a c# desktop application ,so that i can access the data in the database and also need to update the database too.

Since i am relatively new to this thing,i am looking for all sorts of guidance.

Can anyone point me to the right direction of how to achieve this.

Any tutorials or demos available? I searched a little bit but haven't got anything relevant.

Comment: What have you already tried ?

Comment: Hi ,thanks for the early reply. I havent tried anything yet,since i am unaware of the directions .If i get a clue or any important stuffs i will dig into it and get a solution.But i need a direction to travel

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733133.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its so simple if you think it is. You need to build services in WCF, which you want to use in your desktop application. Then you have to add the ***service reference*** to your desktop application. Now your application can access the WCF services hosted in IIS.

You need to study about WCF before you go further. I recommend you to google it for beginners tutorial. You can check it out. [CP WCF tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/406096/A-beginners-tutorial-for-understanding-Windows) and [Saravanakumar's WCF tutorial](http://wcftutorial.net/).

Comment: Thanks Imitiaz ,for the tutorials

Comment: @Imitiaz : will i be able to edit my database?

Comment: Yup, you can. If you want that your services will handle the database. It will work for your desktop application as like another function.

Comment: i added the service refernce ,btu right now i dnt know how to access my database using service applivcation.Can u explain that please?

Comment: i havent written any methods in my service .i just need to access database .

Answer (score 1):

You would start by adding a "service reference" to your desktop application.

1. Right-click the desktop application project. Click **Add Service Reference**
2. Enter the URL for the service you've created, click **Go**. If the service is in the same solution, you could use the **Discover** button instead.
3. Enter a descriptive namespace for the reference at the bottom and click **OK**.
4. For this code example I'm assuming the service is called "MyService" and has an operation `GetData`. My chosen namespace was "MyService". The code to access the service would look something like this.

Service contract:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IMyService
{
    [OperationContract]
    string GetData(int value);
}
```

Client side code:

```
string data;

using (var client = new MyService.MyServiceClient())
{
    data = client.GetData(42);
}
```

There is a [walkthrough on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386386.aspx), which includes creation of the service as well.

Answer (score 1):

To access to service, just create Win form application, find `'References'` folder in your project, right click on it, find `'Add service reference'`, click on it. Then you will see window in `address textbox`, write address to your service,

> example: http://localhost/ServiceFolder/Service1.svc,

then click OK button.

Comment: Done this much,now how can i get the information from the service.like how do i interact with the databse there

Comment: Open browser and go to your service address. example [http://localhost/YourFolder/YourService.svc](). You will see description of how to use service. You will see smth like: YourServiceClient client = new YourServiceClient(). But first of all dont forget add namespace(using ...Service1Reference) to your service reference.

Comment: Checked ,its hsowing like this:<service xml:base="http://Ip/WcfService1_Edu/WcfDataService1.svc/"><workspace><atom:title>Default</atom:title><collection href="Patients"><atom:title>Patients</atom:title></collection><collection href="tblTests"><atom:title>tblTests</atom:title></collection><collection href="tblTestSecs"><atom:title>tblTestSecs</atom:title></collection><collection href="tbSeconds"><atom:title>tbSeconds</atom:title></collection></workspace></service>

Comment: How can i access the table Patients using this?

Comment: If you dont see description page when you go to your service address, it means smth is wrong, check code or config file. Try to find tutorial about WCF services and learn it first. Here you can find examples: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/123067/A-Simple-Sample-WCF-Service or here: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahakgupta/a-simple-example-of-wcf-service/

Comment: actually i only created the WCF service,but i havent wrote any methods in it.Is it like that,i have to write the method for getting data from server?

Comment: Yeah, you need to write method, that will do all your logic.